# How do I upscale my scene to a larger viewport?

Tags: directx10, sharpdx

I want to:

1. Render my scene to a small viewport (some divisor of the full screen size).
2. Stretch the rendered image to cover the full screen size.

For example I want to render a complex, very slow scene at 960x520 and then stretch the resulting image over a full 1920x1040 screen.

`Texture2D.LoadTextureFromTexture()` can achieve that result, but is incredibly slow (far, far too slow for gaming). Similarly, `Device.CopySubresourceRegion()` or `Device.CopyResource()` copies the pixels exactly based on the size of the image, so they don't stretch at all and a 960x520 image will simply take up a corner of the full screen.

I could render the texture onto a quad, but I wanted to know if there was a way to do this programmatically before writing a shader just to stretch an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically already answered your question:

1. Render your scene to a texture of the desired size.
2. Render a full-screen quad with that texture applied.

You only need a very simple shader to perform step 2.

Comment: I was fairly sure of that, which is why I'm halfway through doing it.

Comment: As a final note, it is possible to do this in DirectX9 with a single command, and the operation is much faster.